# encode repeated letters in a string with number

Tags: python

A string 'abc' must become 'a1b1c1'.
String 'aaabcca' - 'a3b1c2a1'

I wrote python function, but it fails to add the last letter and 'abc' is only 'a1b1'.

```
string = "aaabbcc"
coded = ''
if len(string) == 0:
   print('')
else:
  count = 1   #start with the first char, not zero!
  prev = string[0]
  for i in range(1,len(string)):
    current = string[i]
    if current == prev:     
       count +=1
    else:              
      coded += prev
      coded += str(count)
      count = 1
      prev = current
      print("coded string: " + coded)
print(coded)
```

Comment: hint: itertoools.groupby

Comment: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: input letters may be unsorted, right? `wwaaadvc`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to explicitly add the very last iteration.

```
string = "aaabb"
coded = ''
if len(string) == 0:
   print('')
else:
  count = 1   #start with the first char, not zero!
  prev = string[0]
  for i in range(1,len(string)):
    current = string[i]
    if current == prev:     
       count +=1
    else:              
      coded += prev
      coded += str(count)
      count = 1
      prev = current
coded += prev       # these two
coded += str(count) # lines

print(coded)
```

I would prefer a less complicated loop, though:

```
string = "aaabbcc"
coded = ''
while string:
    i = 0
    while i < len(string) and string[0] == string[i]:
        i += 1
    coded += string[0]+str(i)
    string = string[i:]

print(coded)
```

Comment: how can you write "while len(string)" ?

Comment: @ERJAN: uhm. Using my keyboard? Do you see something wrong with it? I did test my code.

Comment: python does not allow this? as condition? len(string) = True? can it be a condtion?

Comment: [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) "tests the expression and, if it is true, executes the first suite". `len(string)` is a number ... ah – you don't need `len(string)`  That's my C shining through I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'aaabcca'
>>> ''.join('{}{}'.format(c, sum(1 for _ in g)) for c, g in groupby(s))
'a3b1c2a1'
```

Details on what `groupby` produces:

```
>>> groups = groupby(s)
>>> [(char, list(group)) for char, group in groups]
[('a', ['a', 'a', 'a']), ('b', ['b']), ('c', ['c', 'c']), ('a', ['a'])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Some *regex* magic:

```
import re

s = 'aaawbbbccddddd'
counts = re.sub(r'(.)\1*', lambda m: m.group(1) + str(len(m.group())), s)
print(counts)
```

The output:

```
a3w1b3c2d5
```

---

*Details*:

regex pattern:

- `(.)` - capturing a character `.`(any char) into the 1st captured group
- `\1*` - matches zero or more consecutive `\1` which is a reference to the 1st captured group value (matching a potentially sequence of the same character)

replacement:

- `m.group(1)` - contains the 1st matched group value
- `str(len(m.group()))` - get length of the entire character sequence matched

Comment: "Daily vote limit reached" – *damn*. I'll be back in a day. Wicked.

Comment: @usr2564301, no problem )

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, can u elaborate on this expression in sub()?

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder why your code didn't work or you don't want to use any external libraries here's working version of your code

```
string = "aaabbcc"
coded = ''

if len(string) == 0:
   print('')

else:
  count = 0
  prev = string[0]
  for i in range(1,len(string)):
    current = string[i]
    count +=1

    if current != prev:
      coded += prev
      coded += str(count)
      count = 0

    prev = current

  coded += current
  coded += str(count+1)

print(coded) # -> a3b2c2
```