# Binary digits string manipulation in Python

Tags: python, string

How do I calculate unique counts of (groups) of 1's and 0's in a string in Python 3? e.g.

```
'11110000110110001111011'
```

Output should be

```
{0:{1, 3, 4} , 1:{2, 4}}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Hi Khalid, please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are quite a few reference on line, including this site, for recognizing sequences of consecutive values.  We expect you to research the problem before posting here.

Comment: *Duplicate*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401193/encode-repeated-letters-in-a-string-with-number

Comment: My sincere apologies, I admit to not reading help/how to ask/code of conduct , and did not search hard enough for similar question on this site.   I promise it will not happen again.
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and add the length of each group to a dict of sets:

```
from itertools import groupby
s = '11110000110110001111011'
d = {}
for k, g in groupby(s):
    d.setdefault(int(k), set()).add(sum(1 for _ in g))
```

`d` becomes:

```
{1: {2, 4}, 0: {1, 3, 4}}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @blhsing , just what I was looking for. I tried with two while statements, and I got into a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `while` loop, by adding difference of index of first character opposite to that on current index and that `idx`, to some list, here values of `counted_x`.

```
x = '11110000110110001111011'
counted_x = {'0': [], '1': []}

idx = 0
while idx < len(x):
    oposite_key = str(abs(int(x[idx])-1))
    if oposite_key in x[idx:]:
        counted_x[x[idx]].append(x.index(oposite_key, idx) - idx)
    else:
        counted_x[x[idx]].append(len(x[idx:]))
    idx += counted_x[x[idx]][-1]

counted_x = [{k: list(set(v))} for k, v in counted_x.items()]
print(counted_x)
```

Output:

```
[{'0': [1, 3, 4]}, {'1': [2, 4]}]
```

Comment: Thank u very much.  I had a similar attempt before posting the question, but I got confused checking for the end of the string so that (index) method will not raise an exception.